# HTTP Request from Python not working, works from other Software

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests, zscaler

I'm trying to make a HTTP request from a python script on my work laptop. Basically I'm trying to automate a process to loop through failed records and send them to a REST API. I can send these records fine through software like Apache JMeter and SoapUI on the exact same computer, but I cannot seem to send the request from my python script.

It is a work computer so it appears any requests getting sent out need to go through a software called zscaler. I'm using the python requests library, and I've tried messing around passing proxy credentials in the request, but still no luck.

When I send the HTTP request without proxy settings, the request just hangs for about 60 seconds then throws an error:

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='********.com', port=443): Max
 retries exceeded with url: /Orchestrator/ProxyService/1.0/ConverterProxy (Caused by
 ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 503 Service Unavailable')))
```

and when I send the request with proxy settings, it gives me back a http status 500 code every time with not many other details (no error is raised, not sure how to see more details from response though)

Does anyone have any ideas what python is doing different to other software which would prevent it from working? Let me know if you'd like any more info provided

Answer (score 0):

Ended up finding out how to make it work, it did require me to pass a set of proxy credentials which I needed to get from my company on what to send !